# Why do I need a UI Thread check

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

To update the UI from an other thread you need to call the BeginInvoke method of the dispatcher. Before you invoke you method you can check whether the calling thread is associated with the dispatcher.

For my example I have 2 ways to update a textbox; by clicking a button and by elapsing a timer. The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int i = 0;
        private TextBlock myText = new TextBlock();
        private Button myButton = new Button();
        private Timer timer = new Timer(2 * 1000);
        private StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myButton.Content = "Click";

            panel.Children.Add(myText);
            panel.Children.Add(myButton);

            this.AddChild(panel);

            myButton.Click += (_, __) => IncrementAndShowCounter();
            timer.Elapsed += (_, __) => IncrementAndShowCounter();

            timer.Start();
        }

        private void IncrementAndShowCounter()
        {
            i++;

            if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                myText.Text = i.ToString();
            }
            else
            {

                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    myText.Text = i.ToString();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I don't CheckAccess() and just always execute the BeginInvoke everything works fine.

So my question is why not always use the BeginInvoke and skip the CheckAccess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is why not always use the `BeginInvoke` and skip the
>   `CheckAccess`?

That's exactly what you should do most of the time *if invoking is required* (i.e. you are touching a control owned by another thread). If invoking is not required then you should skip both of them.

Using `CheckAccess` implies that your code doesn't know or doesn't want to assume that it will run on the "correct" thread. There are two main reasons for this: genericity (your code is in a library and you can't predict how it will be used) and convenience (you want only one method to take care of both cases, or you want the freedom to change the mode of operation without breaking the program).

Your example falls in the second category: the same method services both modes of operation. In this case you have three possible options:

1. **Always invoke without `CheckAccess`.**

   This is going to give you a performance hit (a negligible one here), and it will also make readers of the code assume that the method is only called from worker threads. Since the only benefit is that you will be writing a little less code, this is the worst option.
2. **Keep everything as it is.**

   Since `IncrementAndShowCounter` is called from both UI and worker threads, making it adapt to the situation lets you move on to other problems. This is simple and good; it's also the best you can do when writing library code (no assumptions allowed).
3. **Never invoke from within the method, do it from outside as required.**

   This is the best option on technical merit: since you know the context in which the method will be called, arrange for the invocation to happen outside it. This way the method is not tied to any specific thread and you don't get unnecessary performance penalties.

Here's example code for the third option:

```
private void IncrementAndShowCounter()
{
    i++;
    myText.Text = i.ToString();
}

myButton.Click += (_, __) => IncrementAndShowCounter();
timer.Elapsed += (_, __) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(IncrementAndShowCounter);
```

Comment: What's the performance hit when using `BeginInvoke`? Isn't that just queuing in the Dispatcher's Priority Queue to be executed?

Comment: @lll: I don't know exactly how it's implemented, so guesswork only I 'm afraid. The PQ you mention would need a sync mechanism to be thread-safe; that's one possible penalty.

Comment: First off, there really isn't much of a performance hit.  Adding a delegate to the end of a queue is going to be a very fast operation.  Additionally, as is mentioned in the other answer, you should virtually *always* know whether a given block of code will be called from the UI thread or a non-UI thread.  You should pretty much never be in the position of not knowing if some code is or isn't running in the UI thread.  There is virtually never any reason to programmatically check if you are in the UI thread in production code.

Comment: @Servy There are given scenarios where the code to be executed was created by a "different" `Dispatcher` and you want that to be used in the `Main Dispatcher`.

Comment: @lll Well, first off, I would *strongly* discourage anyone from creating applications with multiple UI threads.  It's virtually always the improper solution to any given problem.  Instead a single UI thread should be used.  That said, even if someone were in the situation you described, then they still *know* that they're not in the right thread, and that they need to invoke to the other dispatcher.  There is no need to conditionally check.

Comment: @Servy Not with `FlowDocuments`. It's a different case. I can see having the single UI Thread for `UIElements` but for `FrameworkContentElements` there are issues where you want another dispatcher to fire while showing a progressbar.

Comment: @lll There is nothing inhibiting someone from showing a progress bar while also performing some other action.  It sounds like you're describing creating a second UI thread because you're blocking the original UI thread to perform non-UI work.  The solution there is to not block the UI thread to do non-UI work, and to instead do the non-UI work in another thread.  That, or it's a sign that you're performing operations synchronously that should be performed asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy Like I said, it's not possible because the data that is required is not in a data that can be separated from the `UI`. Sure it would be true if the `ViewModel` is the only thing that does a long running process while showing a progressbar.

Comment: @lll If it can't be done outside the UI thread, then it should be done asynchronously.  Creating code that blocks the UI thread for an extended period of time and prevents it from pumping messages is almost certainly an improperly designed solution and *that* problem should be fixed, and not through a second UI thread.  However, as I said earlier, even if one *did* choose to use a second UI thread, you still *know* that you're in a different thread from the one that you want to be on, and have no need to check programatically.

Comment: @Servy How can you do it `asynchronously` if it'll end up hogging the `UI thread` (heavy ui)? You just can't. And no, you are not blocking because the `UI thread` is busy updating the `progressbar`. I can see it being asynchronously if it's not a heavy UI job + progresbar. But if it is a heavy UI + progressbar, no.

Comment: @lll Updating a progress bar consumes *very* little effort on the part of the UI thread.  It needs to update very little, and it need to do so very infrequently from the point of a computer in order to seem responsive from the point of view of a person.  A more involved UI process that *is* going to demand an extended amount of time and a significant amount of processing power can indeed be managed asynchronously, and in such a way as to keep the message pump pumping.  One simply needs to break up that operation into many smaller operations.  Other messages can then take place between them.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not sure what your point is regarding the magnitude of the perf hit. That one should invoke always? Surely not, so I'm confused. You also talk about knowing when you need to invoke; I agree and in fact that's what I'm saying too: directly when you can, invoke when you must. `CheckAccess` *is* sometimes necessary, and while I did not mention it that doesn't mean I recommend the same naive conditional pasted all over your code. I don't see where we disagree exactly.

Comment: @Jon One should almost never be in the situation of not knowing whether the code is running in the UI thread or not in the UI thread.  A well designed program prevents that situation from occurring.  In the unusual situation in which you are genuinely unsure, there really isn't any problem with *always* invoking, without checking.  The performance hit you describe is going to be entirely negligible, especially considering it's a situation that should almost never happen.  It's premature optimization of a micro-optimization.

Comment: @Servy If a heavy UI code is doing some code, the progress bar will not be updating its `Value` but will just be showing progress from `0` to `100` for an instance. Like I said, `FlowDocuments` are coupled with its `Child` elements so you cannot separate them at all. It's not like you can split them into unit of works so that the UI won't be hog.

Comment: @Servy so? I don't recommend checking the thread as a habit, so why do you keep bringing it up? I think I answered the question directly and better than "just invoke all the time", which is IMO cargo cult programming. What exactly is your objection to the answer above?

Comment: @Jon I agree with Jon. You don't want to keep calling `CheckAccess` if you know that there will be only one thread entering that code. But if there are parts of code that are open where different dispatchers can execute them, then yes you have to call `CheckAccess` or `VerifyAccess`

Comment: @Jon My objection is that even if one is in the horrendous position in which you don't know whether the currently executing code is in the UI thread or not, there is *still* no compelling reason to programmatically check if you are in the UI thread.  If one is in that horrendous position, simply call `Invoke` unconditionally.  There's no need to check first.  Performance is not a good reason to perform the check.

Comment: @Servy: let's turn the drama down a little. ObservableCollection checks threads and it's because of genericity, not horror. I agree that performance is most likely not a compelling reason to check, and invite you to find the part of the answer that says otherwise so I can fix it.

Comment: @Jon Your answer has two sentences.  One that says you should perform the check before invoking for performance reasons, and one that says something else.  I would hope that you can figure out on your own which of them is stating that performance is the reason why you should call CheckAccess before invoking.

Comment: @Servy sorry, but neither the word check nor any of its synonyms is or has ever been included in the answer. I honestly believe you misread it. While I have no objection to clarifying in the interests of improving it, I feel you are just putting words in my mouth here. Note that the question being answered is "why shouldn't I always invoke?"

Comment: @Jon Question: "Why not always use the BeginInvoke and skip the CheckAccess?" Answer: "Because there is a performance hit when you use BeginInvoke compared with just running the code directly."  In what way is that *not* saying that performance is why you should be calling `CheckAccess` before invoking?  I don't see performance as being a consideration at all, the performance differences are just going to be that small.  Perhaps the developer imagined that there ought to be a performance hit when there really isn't, and that's why, but I can't see this *actually* being a valid optimization.

Comment: @Servy fair enough, although by now you realise that's not want I meant at all. Your position also implies that the answer to "why not" is "because you don't need to", which is in my opinion no answer at all ("so what? why would I not do it anyway, especially since it involves *less* code?"). The only reason to refrain from invoking all the things vs checking when unsure is perf. I'll improve the answer when I get to a PC.

Comment: @Servy: I edited the answer. To be frank I have mixed feelings about the edit because I think that it now goes off on tangents. Your thoughts?

Comment: It's certainly a lot better than it was before.  The only real complaint that comes to mind, and this is much more minor, is that in library UI code you often *can* document a constraint that it be run in the UI thread, and leave the responsibility to the caller to always marshal to the UI thread before accessing your objects (in just the same way that the `TextBlock` here requires that constraint of the user, as it's library code too) but that issue doesn't really bother me much at all because people writing libraries will know such things already.

Answer (score 2):

If you 100% sure that the calling thread is UI thread - you can use the "DO" method directly.

If you 100% sure that the calling thread is not UI thread, but the operation should be done on the UI thread, you just call the **BeginInvoke**

```
....
// 100% I'm sure the Click handler will be invoked on UI thread
myButton.Click += (_, __) => IncrementAndShowCounter();
// here I'm not sure
timer.Elapsed += (_, __) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(IncrementAndShowCounter); 
// 100%  not UI thred here:
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(IncrementAndShowCounter), TaskScheduler.Default)


private void IncrementAndShowCounter()
{
    i++;
    myText.Text = i.ToString();
}
```